# High performance table structure for really small tables (<10 items usually) where once the table is created it doesn't change?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, data-structures, hashmap

I am searching for a high performance C++ structure for a table. The table will have void* as keys and uint32 as values.

The table itself is very small and will not change after creation. The first idea that came to my mind is using something like `ska::flat_hash_map<void*, int32_t>` or `std::unordered_map<void*, int32_t>`. However that will be overkill and will not provide me the performance I want (those tables are suited for high number of items too).

So I thought about using `std::vector<std::pair<void*, int32_t>>`, sorting it upon creation and linear probing it. The next ideas will be using SIMD instructions but it is possible with the current structure.

Another solution which I will shortly evaluate is like that:

```
struct Group
{
    void* items[5]; // search using SIMD
    int32_t items[5]; 
}; // fits in cache line

struct Table
{
     Group* groups;
     size_t capacity;
};
```

Are there any better options? I need only 1 operation: finding values by keys, not modifying them, not anything. Thanks!

EDIT: another thing I think I should mention are the access patterns: suppose I have an array of those hash tables, each time I will look up from a random one in the array.

Comment: std::unordered_map with such a low number of entries will look up your values most probably in O(1). It will use hashes and be very fast. If you can use something different than a void* (which is strange in the first place), maybe an id of some sort, then you can use a plain C-Style array.

Comment: Before dismissing solutions, benchmark them. Try to create a small program that runs the typical operations you need on the tables, a couple of million times, and then report the average time. Remember to build your benchmarking program with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @Some programmer dude What do you propose as a alternative solution for the benchmark?

Comment: @ArminMontigny I don't want O(1).. I want speed. Sometimes O(n) will be faster than O(1) friend. std::unordered_map keeps elements scattered across memory plus is 72 bytes size and just negates the access patterns which I am going to use it.

Comment: If you know the upper boundary of the table, there's no point on using vector. Just use an `std::array` and an unsigned integral value for the size (if it can change). Linear probing sounds the best candidate, but I would use a struct of arrays instead of keeping the values in pairs (so you only iterate over packed pointers when searching). In any case, you must evaluate before making any conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into perfect hashing -- not too difficult, and can provide simple constant time lookups.  It can take technically unbounded time to create the table, though, and it's not as fast as a regular hash table when the regular hash table gets lucky.

I think a nice alternative is an optimization of your simple linear probing idea.

Your lookup procedure would look like this:

```
Slot *s = &table[hash(key)];
Slot *e = s + s->max_extent;
for (;s<e; ++s) {
    if (s->key == key) {
        return s->value;
    }
}
return NOT_FOUND;
```

`table[h].max_extent` is the maximum number of elements you may have to look at if you're looking for an element with hash code `h`. You would pre-calculate this when you generate the table, so your lookup doesn't have to iterate until it gets a null. This greatly reduces the amount of probing you have to do for misses.

Of course you want `max_extent` to be as small as possible.  Pick a hash result size (at least 2n) to make it <= 1 in most cases, and try a few different hash functions before picking the one that produces the best results by whatever metric you like.  You hash can be as simple as `key % P`, where trying different hashes means trying different P values.  Fill your hash table in `hash(key)` order to produce the best result.

NOTE that we do not wrap around from the end to the start of the table while probing.  Just allocate however many extra slots you need to avoid it.

Comment: What is max_extent? I am not fluent in english :/

Comment: `table[h].max_extent` is the maximum number of elements you may have to look at if you're looking for an element with hash code `h`.  You would pre-calculate this when you generate the table, so your lookup doesn't have to iterate until it gets a null.  This greatly reduces the amount of probing you have to do for misses.  In most cases it will limit you to 1 key check.

Comment: oh, good idea! I may go for it but I need to check other options first. this is especially good if I use ```std::pair<void*, int>``` since it shouldn't have any memory overhead: it will be stored right after the int and there will be 3 bytes padding instead of 4

Comment: For your use case, a Slot should be `{void *key, uint32_t max_extent, uint32_t value}` .  `max_extent` fits into the padding that would otherwise be wasted.  I think that's what you meant, but maybe not.

Comment: yeah thats exaclty what I meant in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Linear probing is likely the fastest solution in this case on common mainstream architectures, especially since the number of element is very small and bounded (ie. <10). Sorting the items should not speed up the probing with so few items (it would be only useful for a binary search which is much more expensive in this case).

If you want to use SIMD instruction, then you need to use structure of arrays instead of array of structures for the sake of performance. This means you should use `std::pair<std::vector<void*>, std::vector<int32_t>>` instead of `std::vector<std::pair<void*, int32_t>>` (which alternates `void*` types and `int32_t` values in memory with some padding overhead due to the alignment constraints of `void*` on 64-bit architectures). Having two `std::vector` is not great too because you pay its overhead twice. As mentioned by @JorgeBellon
in the comments, you can simply use a `std::array` instead of `std::vector` assuming the number of items is known or bounded.

A possible optimization with SIMD instructions is to compact the key pointers on 64-bit architectures by splitting them in 32-bit lower/upper part. Indeed, it is very unlikely that two pointers have the same lower part (least significant bits) while having a different upper part. This tricks help you to check 2 times more pointers at a time.

Note that using SIMD instructions may not be so great in this case in practice. This is especially true if the number of items is smaller than the one fitting in a SIMD vector. For example, with AVX2 (on 86-64 processors), you can work on 4 64-bit values at a time (or 8 32-bit values) but if you have less than 8 values, then you need to *mask* the unwanted values to check (or even not load them if the memory buffer do not contain some *padding*). This introduces an additional overhead. This is not much a problem with AVX-512 and SVE (only available on a small fraction of processors yet) since they provides advanced masking operations. Moreover, some processors lower they *frequency* when they execute SIMD instructions (especially with AVX-512 although the down-clocking is not so strong with integer instructions). SIMD instructions also introduce some additional *latency* compared to scalar version (which can be better pipelined) and modern processors tends to be able to execute more scalar instructions in parallel than SIMD ones. For all these reasons, it is certainly a good idea to try to write a scalar *branchless* implementation (possibly *unrolled* for better performance if the number of items is known at compile time).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I definitely learned a lot. I know that a lot of the times SOA is better then AOS however in my use case I am afraid that a double cache miss may occur.
May I ask how would it even be possible to write a branchless implementation? You would always need an if to check if current is the needed key...

Comment: Also what did you mean by splitting pointers into 2 32-bit integers? I know a pointer is an integer of course but what will you do with those 2 32-bit integers besides comparing them too?

Comment: The two arrays can be stored in a contiguous section of the memory and aligned to a cache line. 5 items can fit in a unique 64-byte cache line. For 5 to 10 items, the number of cache miss will be the same. Modern processors can load 2 consecutive cache lines simultaneously because of out-of-order superscalar execution. So I do not think cache miss a bigger problem with SOA if done carefully.

Comment: For the branchless implementation, you can use conditional move instructions. The idea is to move the index of the value in a result register if the pointer match. I think you can write a pretty fast code if it is totally unrolled using such instructions. Be careful though because data-dependent instructions can only be executed serially. Thus, you may need to break the dependency chain using a *reduction* pattern.

Comment: By splitting I mean that you can convert a 64-bit pointer `p` to 2 32-bit integers: `uint32_t hi = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)p) >> 32);` and `uint32_t lo = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)p) & 0xFFFFFFFF);`. This is a bit low level and not portable on all platform but it should be OK on all mainstream 64-bit platforms. The Idea is to store the `lo` values first, then the uint32 value and then the `hi` value. The result should be more compact in cache and faster to load. The `hi` part is often always the same on processes using less than 4 GiB RAM (with memory allocated in the same library module AFAIK).

Comment: So generally discard the high isn't what I am looking for because while I don't mind supporting only 64-bit platforms I don't want to rely on the fact that the process uses less than 4 GB RAM (though I might(?)), so you're idea is just forget the high bits and store it in pairs like ```std::pair<uint32_t, int>``` where int is the field? because if not, you will always end up having to compare with the high bits too, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have read it again and can see that you say storing the high bits too, but what advantage will I get from this if I will always end up comparing the high bits too? isn't a 64-bit comparasion faster than 2 32-bit comparasions?

Comment: OHHH I could do that
```__builtin_prefetch(values);return values[linear_search(keys, needed_key)];```
tbh I may end up using that, I will need to measure! thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240189/discussion-between-jerome-richard-and-null).